How Do I Prevent the Google Login Prompt from Showing Despite Being Logged in in my Angular App with Routing using the AngularX Social Login module?
I have an Angular app that uses routing to go between, essentially, two "pages" - a data recording screen and an analysis report screen. I am using the AngularX Social Login (https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login] module with Google as my provider in my app.
Logging on with Google is fine. However, once logged in, when I switch between pages, the google prompt comes up each time.

For example, if I am logged in using Google and I record some data, when I switch to the analysis screen, a google popup appears. It knows I am logged in, and knows who I am logged in as, and it offers a confirmation with a "Continue as user" button.

In my application, my index.html is essentially
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>

 <body>
  <app-root></app-root>
 </body>
</html>

My routing is
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'record', component: RecordComponent },
  { path: 'analyse', component: AnalyseComponent },
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/record', pathMatch: 'full' }, // redirect to `record`
];

My AppModule's config is
providers: [
 {
  provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
  useValue: {
    autoLogin: false,
    providers: [
      {
        id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
          'foo.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        )
      }
    ],
    onError: (err) => {
      console.error(err);
    }
  } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
 }
],

My AppComponent is
export class AppComponent {
  user: SocialUser = null;

  constructor(
    private _authService: SocialAuthService
  ) {
    this._authService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }
}

and its HTML is
<div class="container">

 <div *ngIf="!user">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <asl-google-signin-button type='standard' size='medium'></asl-google-signin-button>
 </div>

 <div *ngIf="user">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </div>
</div>

I am using Angular 16 (16.2.2) and angularx-social-login version 2.1.0.

doesn't look like this creates any kind of session.  You'd need to implement that on server-side.  You're just getting a username client-side here but there's no call to authenticate or authorize them with your server.  If all you want to do is get their google login name, then store it, maybe in a service or a cookie and check for its existence before calling the google login provider.

@browsermator, I am only using google for user authentication. I don't need access to any Google services, but I use the Google id as my user identifier.

then you need some kind of "session". (login) Probably via an access token/refresh token pair. (for supposedly "session-less" session) How is the back-end handling this?   Right now Google is logging in the user to Google, then Google is giving your front-end some information about them.  They are not logged in to your server.  (via cookie, or header value...)

It looks like SocialUser will have "authToken" and "idToken".  See here about authenticating: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Have you found a solution? I experience the same issue here.
